# Battle ship game

Tags: c++, game

I have been programming for a couple months now and really wanted to make my own game, so I chose battle ship due to is simplicity (I learned out how wrong I was). I know one thing I am going to hear about is that it isn't portable due to the fact I am using the windows library. All I have to say is I tried finding other ways but sadly I am not smart enough. I would also love to convert it to OOP, but I have no idea how to start.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <limits>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

const int COLS = 10;
const int ROWS = 10;
const int CARRIER = 5;
const int BATTLE_SHIP = 4;
const int CRUISER = 3;
const int SUBMARINE = 3;
const int PATROL = 2;
//Prototypes
void playerSetUp(HANDLE, char[][COLS], int, int playerCarrier[], int playerBattleShip[], int playerCruiser[], int playerSubmarine[], int playerPatrol[]);
void mapGenerator(char[][COLS], int, int carrier[], int battleShip[], int cruiser[], int submarine[], int patrol[]);
void displayScoreBoard(HANDLE, char[][COLS], char[][COLS], int, int enemyCarrier[], int enemyBattleShip[], int enemyCruiser[], int enemySubmarine[], int enemyPatrol[], int &, int &, int &, int &, int &, int &, int &, int &, int &, int &, int playerCarrier[], int playerBattleShip[], int playerCruiser[], int playerSubmarine[], int playerPatrol[]);
void placeCursor(HANDLE, int, int);
int winCondition(int, int);
int startMenu();
int shipCheck(char[][COLS], int, int ship[], int);
int letterVal(char);
int numValidation(int);
void displayBoard(HANDLE, char[][COLS], int);
void playerTurn(HANDLE, char[][COLS], char[][COLS], int);
void enemyTurn(HANDLE, char[][COLS], int, int);
void stringInputCheck(HANDLE, string, int&, int&, int, int);

int main()
{
    //computer map
    char computer[ROWS][COLS] = {
        { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' },
        { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' },
        { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' },
        { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' },
        { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' },
        { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' },
        { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' },
        { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' },
        { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' },
        { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' },
    };
    //map the player will see
    char enemyDisplay[ROWS][COLS] = {
        { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' },
        { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' },
        { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' },
        { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' },
        { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' },
        { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' },
        { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' },
        { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' },
        { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' },
        { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' },
    };
    //player map
    char player[ROWS][COLS] = {
        { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' },
        { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' },
        { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' },
        { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' },
        { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' },
        { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' },
        { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' },
        { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' },
        { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' },
        { 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O' },
    };
    int startNumber, gameOver;
    int enemyCarrier[7], enemyBattleShip[6], enemyCruiser[5], enemySubmarine[5], enemyPatrol[4];            //holds numbers for points of ship location
    int playerCarrier[7], playerBattleShip[6], playerCruiser[5], playerPatrol[4];       //holds numbers for points of ship location
    int playerSubmarine[5];
    int enemyCarrierAlive = 1, enemyBattleShipAlive = 1, enemyCruiserAlive = 1, enemySubmarineAlive = 1, enemyPatrolAlive = 1;      //1 = ship alive 2 = ship dead
    int playerCarrierAlive = 1, playerBattleShipAlive = 1, playerCruiserAlive = 1, playerSubmarineAlive = 1, playerPatrolAlive = 1; //1 = ship alive 2 = ship dead
    int enemyAlive, playerAlive;                            //holds number 1-5 for how many ships are left

    HANDLE screen = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);        //needed for color and cursor control

    startNumber = startMenu();                              //gets player choice for difficulty
    if (startNumber == 1 || startNumber == 2){
        system("CLS");
        playerSetUp(screen, player, ROWS, playerCarrier, playerBattleShip, playerCruiser, playerSubmarine, playerPatrol);                                   //function that lets player place ships accordingly
        mapGenerator(computer, ROWS, enemyCarrier, enemyBattleShip, enemyCruiser, enemySubmarine, enemyPatrol); //function that sets computer ships
        do{
            placeCursor(screen, 0, 0);                                      //places cursor for boards
            displayBoard(screen, enemyDisplay, ROWS);                       //displays computer board
            displayBoard(screen, player, ROWS);                             //displays player board
            displayScoreBoard(screen, player, computer, ROWS, enemyCarrier, enemyBattleShip, enemyCruiser, enemySubmarine, enemyPatrol, enemyCarrierAlive, enemyBattleShipAlive, enemyCruiserAlive, enemySubmarineAlive, enemyPatrolAlive, playerCarrierAlive, playerBattleShipAlive, playerCruiserAlive, playerSubmarineAlive, playerPatrolAlive, playerCarrier, playerBattleShip, playerCruiser, playerSubmarine, playerPatrol);              //displays score board
            playerTurn(screen, computer, enemyDisplay, ROWS);               //lets player choose a point to attack
            enemyTurn(screen, player, COLS, startNumber);                   //computer chooses a point to attack
            enemyAlive = enemyCarrierAlive + enemyBattleShipAlive + enemyCruiserAlive + enemySubmarineAlive + enemyPatrolAlive;
            playerAlive = playerCarrierAlive + playerBattleShipAlive + playerCruiserAlive + playerSubmarineAlive + playerPatrolAlive;
            gameOver = winCondition(enemyAlive, playerAlive);               //checks if all ships are destroyed
        } while (gameOver == 1);
        if (gameOver == 2){
            system("CLS");
            placeCursor(screen, 0, 0);
            cout << "You Win!" << endl;
            cin.get();
        }
        else{
            system("CLS");
            placeCursor(screen, 0, 0);
            cout << "You Lost!" << endl;
            cin.get();
        }
    }
    else{
        char quitKey;
        cout << "Press any key then enter to exit: ";
        cin >> quitKey;
    }


    return 0;
}
//This function lets the player pick between playing or quitting, then from computer or human, then from which difficulty
int startMenu(){
    int start;
    char choice;
    cout << "\t\tBattle Ship Game 1.0\n\n\n";
    cout << "This game is real beta stuff right now." << endl;
    cout << "Please press the maxmize screen button for best quality." << endl << endl << endl;
    cout << "A. Start \nB. Quit\nChoose: ";
    cin >> choice;
    while (!(choice == 'A' || choice == 'a' || choice == 'B' || choice == 'b' || choice == 'C' || choice == 'c')){
        cout << "Invalid choice. Please select A, B, or C: ";
        cin >> choice;
    }
    if (choice == 'A' || choice == 'a'){
        cout << "Would you like to face the computer or another person?" << endl;
        cout << "A. Computer\nB. Human\nC. Quit" << endl;
        cout << "Your choice: ";
        cin >> choice;
        while (!(choice == 'A' || choice == 'a' || choice == 'B' || choice == 'b' || choice == 'C' || choice == 'c')){
            cout << "Invalid choice. Please select A, B, or C: ";
            cin >> choice;
        }
        if (choice == 'A' || choice == 'a'){
            cout << "What difficulty would you like?" << endl;
            cout << "A. Easy\nB. Medium\nC. Hard (Under Construction}" << endl;
            cout << "Your choice: ";
            cin >> choice;
            if (choice == 'A' || choice == 'a'){
                start = 1;
            }
            else if (choice == 'B' || choice == 'b'){
                start = 2;
            }
            else{
                cout << "Hard still under constuction. Loading Medium difficulty.";
                start = 2;
            }
        }
        else if (choice == 'B' || choice == 'b'){
            cout << "Still under construction. Now exiting program." << endl;
            start = 0;
        }
        else
            start = 0;
    }
    else
        start = 0;
    return start;
}
//This function displays the game board of the player or the computer
void displayBoard(HANDLE screen, char map[][COLS], int row){
    cout << "    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9" << endl;
    cout << "  -----------------------\n";
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++){
        if (x == 0)
            cout << "A ";
        if (x == 1)
            cout << "B ";
        if (x == 2)
            cout << "C ";
        if (x == 3)
            cout << "D ";
        if (x == 4)
            cout << "E ";
        if (x == 5)
            cout << "F ";
        if (x == 6)
            cout << "G ";
        if (x == 7)
            cout << "H ";
        if (x == 8)
            cout << "I ";
        if (x == 9)
            cout << "J ";
        cout << "| ";
        for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++){
            if (map[x][y] == 'O'){
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(screen, 7);
                cout << map[x][y] << " ";
            }
            else if (map[x][y] == 'A'){
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(screen, 1);
                cout << map[x][y] << " ";
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(screen, 7);
            }
            else if(map[x][y] == 'M'){
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(screen, 6);
                cout << map[x][y] << " ";
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(screen, 7);
            }
            else{
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(screen, 4);
                cout << map[x][y] << " ";
                SetConsoleTextAttribute(screen, 7);
            }
        }
        cout << "|";
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "  -----------------------\n";
}
//This function will allow the player to place his ships anywhere on the array.
void playerSetUp(HANDLE screen, char playerSetUp[][COLS], int rows, int playerCarrier[], int playerBattleShip[], int playerCruiser[], int playerSubmarine[], int playerPatrol[]){
    static int shipCount = 0;
    int place1 = 0, place2 = 0, place3 = 0, place4 = 0, shipSize, sizeDifference;
    string shipName, point;
    int overLapCheck = 1;
    char choice;


    displayBoard(screen, playerSetUp, ROWS);
    cout << "Welcome to BattleShip! This is your board where you get to place your ships!" << endl;
    cout << "Please type the letter followed by the number (example: a6) then press enter." << endl;
    cout << "Then type in the second coordinate in the same format. Please only place ships" << endl;
    cout << "from left to right or from up to down. The game will crash otherwise :(" << endl;
    cout << "Do you wish to place your ships manually or have a randomly generated board?" << endl;
    cout << "Type A to make your own board or B to have one make for you: ";
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice == 'A' || choice == 'a'){
        do{
            system("CLS");

            displayBoard(screen, playerSetUp, ROWS);

            if (shipCount == 0){
                shipName = "carrier";
                shipSize = CARRIER;
            }
            else if (shipCount == 1){
                shipName = "battle_ship";
                shipSize = BATTLE_SHIP;
            }
            else if (shipCount == 2){
                shipName = "cruiser";
                shipSize = CRUISER;
            }
            else if (shipCount == 3){
                shipName = "submarine";
                shipSize = SUBMARINE;
            }
            else if (shipCount == 4){
                shipName = "patrol";
                shipSize = PATROL;
            }
            cout << "Placing " << shipName << " that is " << shipSize << " spaces long." << endl;
            cout << "Please type the letter first followed by the number\nfor one point followed by the other point" << endl;
            placeCursor(screen, 17, 0);
            cout << "First point(e.g. a5)" << endl;
            /*cin.ignore();*/
            stringInputCheck(screen, point, place1, place2, 18, 0);
            /*cin >> placer1;
            place1 = letterVal(placer1);
            cin >> placer2;
            place2 = numValidation(placer2);*/
            placeCursor(screen, 19, 0);
            cout << "                  " << endl;
            placeCursor(screen, 17, 0);
            cout << "Second point (e.g. a8)" << endl;
            /*cin.ignore();*/
            stringInputCheck(screen, point, place3, place4, 18, 0);
            /*cin >> placer3;
            place3 = letterVal(placer3);
            cin >> placer4;
            place4 = numValidation(placer4);*/
            if (place1 == place3){
                sizeDifference = place4 - place2 + 1;
                if (sizeDifference == shipSize){
                    for (int x = place2; x <= place4; x++){
                        if (playerSetUp[place1][x] == 'O'){
                            overLapCheck = 1;
                        }
                        else{
                            overLapCheck = 2;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (overLapCheck == 1){
                        for (int x = place2, t = 2; x <= place4; x++, t++){
                            if (shipCount == 0){
                                playerCarrier[0] = 1;
                                playerCarrier[1] = place1;
                                playerCarrier[t] = x;
                            }
                            else if (shipCount == 1){
                                playerBattleShip[0] = 1;
                                playerBattleShip[1] = place1;
                                playerBattleShip[t] = x;
                            }
                            else if (shipCount == 2){
                                playerCruiser[0] = 1;
                                playerCruiser[1] = place1;
                                playerCruiser[t] = x;
                            }
                            else if (shipCount == 3){
                                playerSubmarine[0] = 1;
                                playerSubmarine[1] = place1;
                                playerSubmarine[t] = x;
                            }
                            else{
                                playerPatrol[0] = 1;
                                playerPatrol[1] = place1;
                                playerPatrol[t] = x;
                            }
                            playerSetUp[place1][x] = 'A';
                            system("CLS");
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        system("CLS");
                        cout << "You already have a ship there!" << endl;
                        shipCount--;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    do{
                        system("CLS");
                        cout << "Invalid size." << endl;
                        displayBoard(screen, playerSetUp, ROWS);
                        cout << "Placing " << shipName << " that is " << shipSize << " spaces long." << endl;
                        cout << "Please type the letter first followed by the number\nfor one point followed by the other point" << endl;
                        placeCursor(screen, 17, 0);
                        cout << "First point(e.g. a5)" << endl;
                        /*cin.ignore();*/
                        stringInputCheck(screen, point, place1, place2, 18, 0);
                        /*cin >> placer1;
                        place1 = letterVal(placer1);
                        cin >> placer2;
                        place2 = numValidation(placer2);*/
                        placeCursor(screen, 19, 0);
                        cout << "                  " << endl;
                        placeCursor(screen, 17, 0);
                        cout << "Second point (e.g. a8): ";
                        /*cin.ignore();*/
                        stringInputCheck(screen, point, place3, place4, 18, 0);
                        /*cin >> placer3;
                        place3 = letterVal(placer3);
                        cin >> placer4;
                        place4 = numValidation(placer4);*/
                        sizeDifference = place4 - place2 + 1;
                    } while (sizeDifference != shipSize && overLapCheck == 2);
                    for (int x = place2; x <= place4; x++){
                        if (playerSetUp[place1][x] == 'O'){
                            overLapCheck = 1;
                        }
                        else{
                            overLapCheck = 2;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (overLapCheck == 1){
                        for (int x = place2, t = 2; x <= place4; x++, t++){
                            if (shipCount == 0){
                                playerCarrier[0] = 1;
                                playerCarrier[1] = place1;
                                playerCarrier[t] = x;
                            }
                            else if (shipCount == 1){
                                playerBattleShip[0] = 1;
                                playerBattleShip[1] = place1;
                                playerBattleShip[t] = x;
                            }
                            else if (shipCount == 2){
                                playerCruiser[0] = 1;
                                playerCruiser[1] = place1;
                                playerCruiser[t] = x;
                            }
                            else if (shipCount == 3){
                                playerSubmarine[0] = 1;
                                playerSubmarine[1] = place1;
                                playerSubmarine[t] = x;
                            }
                            else{
                                playerPatrol[0] = 1;
                                playerPatrol[1] = place1;
                                playerPatrol[t] = x;
                            }
                            playerSetUp[place1][x] = 'A';
                            system("CLS");
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        system("CLS");
                        cout << "You already have a ship there!" << endl;
                        shipCount--;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (place2 == place4){
                sizeDifference = place3 - place1 + 1;
                if (sizeDifference == shipSize){
                    for (int x = place1; x <= place3; x++){
                        if (playerSetUp[x][place2] == 'O'){
                            overLapCheck = 1;
                        }
                        else{
                            overLapCheck = 2;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (overLapCheck == 1){
                        for (int x = place1, t = 2; x <= place3; x++, t++){
                            if (shipCount == 0){
                                playerCarrier[0] = 2;
                                playerCarrier[1] = place2;
                                playerCarrier[t] = x;
                            }
                            else if (shipCount == 1){
                                playerBattleShip[0] = 2;
                                playerBattleShip[1] = place2;
                                playerBattleShip[t] = x;
                            }
                            else if (shipCount == 2){
                                playerCruiser[0] = 2;
                                playerCruiser[1] = place2;
                                playerCruiser[t] = x;
                            }
                            else if (shipCount == 3){
                                playerSubmarine[0] = 2;
                                playerSubmarine[1] = place2;
                                playerSubmarine[t] = x;
                            }
                            else{
                                playerPatrol[0] = 2;
                                playerPatrol[1] = place2;
                                playerPatrol[t] = x;
                            }
                            playerSetUp[x][place2] = 'A';
                            system("CLS");
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        system("CLS");
                        cout << "You already have a ship there!" << endl;
                        shipCount--;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    do{
                        system("CLS");
                        displayBoard(screen, playerSetUp, ROWS);
                        cout << "Invalid size." << endl;
                        cout << "Placing " << shipName << " that is " << shipSize << " spaces long." << endl;
                        cout << "Please type the letter first followed by the number\nfor one point followed by the other point" << endl;
                        placeCursor(screen, 17, 0);
                        cout << "First point (e.g. a5)" << endl;
                        /*cin.ignore();*/
                        stringInputCheck(screen, point, place1, place2, 18, 0);
                        /*cin >> placer1;
                        place1 = letterVal(placer1);
                        cin >> placer2;
                        place2 = numValidation(placer2);*/
                        placeCursor(screen, 19, 0);
                        cout << "                  " << endl;
                        placeCursor(screen, 17, 0);
                        cout << "Second point (e.g. a8)" << endl;
                        /*cin.ignore();*/
                        stringInputCheck(screen, point, place3, place4, 18, 0);
                        /*cin >> placer3;
                        place3 = letterVal(placer3);
                        cin >> placer4;
                        place4 = numValidation(placer4);*/
                        sizeDifference = place4 - place2 + 1;
                    } while (sizeDifference != shipSize && overLapCheck == 2);
                    for (int x = place1; x <= place3; x++){
                        if (playerSetUp[place1][x] == 'O'){
                            overLapCheck = 1;
                        }
                        else{
                            overLapCheck = 2;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (overLapCheck == 1){
                        for (int x = place1, t = 2; x <= place3; x++, t++){
                            if (shipCount == 0){
                                playerCarrier[0] = 2;
                                playerCarrier[1] = place2;
                                playerCarrier[t] = x;
                            }
                            else if (shipCount == 1){
                                playerBattleShip[0] = 2;
                                playerBattleShip[1] = place2;
                                playerBattleShip[t] = x;
                            }
                            else if (shipCount == 2){
                                playerCruiser[0] = 2;
                                playerCruiser[1] = place2;
                                playerCruiser[t] = x;
                            }
                            else if (shipCount == 3){
                                playerSubmarine[0] = 2;
                                playerSubmarine[1] = place2;
                                playerSubmarine[t] = x;
                            }
                            else{
                                playerPatrol[0] = 2;
                                playerPatrol[1] = place2;
                                playerPatrol[t] = x;
                            }
                            playerSetUp[place1][x] = 'A';
                            system("CLS");
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        system("CLS");
                        cout << "You already have a ship there!" << endl;
                        shipCount--;
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                system("CLS");
                cout << "Must enter ships vertical or horizontal." << endl;
                cout << "Please enter the smaller point first followed by the bigger point." << endl;
                shipCount--;
            }
            shipCount++;
        } while (shipCount <= 4);
    }
    else{
        mapGenerator(playerSetUp, ROWS, playerCarrier, playerBattleShip, playerCruiser, playerSubmarine, playerPatrol);
        system("CLS");
    }
}
//This function makes the computer make a random map for the 5 ships
void mapGenerator(char setUp[][COLS], int rows, int carrier[], int battleShip[], int cruiser[], int submarine[], int patrol[]){
    int computerShipDirection, computerPoint1, computerPoint2; //1 = horizontal 2 = vertical
    int overLapCheck;

    srand(time(0));
    //place carrier
    computerShipDirection = rand() % 2 + 1;
    if (computerShipDirection == 1){                //horizontal
        computerPoint1 = rand() % 10;
        computerPoint2 = rand() % 6;
        setUp[computerPoint1][computerPoint2] = 'A';
        setUp[computerPoint1][computerPoint2 + 1] = 'A';
        setUp[computerPoint1][computerPoint2 + 2] = 'A';
        setUp[computerPoint1][computerPoint2 + 3] = 'A';
        setUp[computerPoint1][computerPoint2 + 4] = 'A';
        carrier[0] = computerShipDirection;
        carrier[1] = computerPoint1;
        carrier[2] = computerPoint2;
        carrier[3] = computerPoint2 + 1;
        carrier[4] = computerPoint2 + 2;
        carrier[5] = computerPoint2 + 3;
        carrier[6] = computerPoint2 + 4;
    }
    else{                                               //vertical
        computerPoint1 = rand() % 6;
        computerPoint2 = rand() % 10;
        setUp[computerPoint1][computerPoint2] = 'A';
        setUp[computerPoint1 + 1][computerPoint2] = 'A';
        setUp[computerPoint1 + 2][computerPoint2] = 'A';
        setUp[computerPoint1 + 3][computerPoint2] = 'A';
        setUp[computerPoint1 + 4][computerPoint2] = 'A';
        carrier[0] = computerShipDirection;
        carrier[1] = computerPoint2;
        carrier[2] = computerPoint1;
        carrier[3] = computerPoint1 + 1;
        carrier[4] = computerPoint1 + 2;
        carrier[5] = computerPoint1 + 3;
        carrier[6] = computerPoint1 + 4;
    }
    //place battleship
    do{
        computerShipDirection = rand() % 2 + 1;
        if (computerShipDirection == 1){                //horizontal
            computerPoint1 = rand() % 10;
            computerPoint2 = rand() % 7;
            for (int z = computerPoint2; z < computerPoint2 + 3; z++){
                if (setUp[computerPoint1][z] == 'O'){
                    overLapCheck = 1;
                }
                else{
                    overLapCheck = 2;
                    break;
                }
            }
                if (overLapCheck == 1){
                    setUp[computerPoint1][computerPoint2] = 'A';
                    setUp[computerPoint1][computerPoint2 + 1] = 'A';
                    setUp[computerPoint1][computerPoint2 + 2] = 'A';
                    setUp[computerPoint1][computerPoint2 + 3] = 'A';
                    battleShip[0] = computerShipDirection;
                    battleShip[1] = computerPoint1;
                    battleShip[2] = computerPoint2;
                    battleShip[3] = computerPoint2 + 1;
                    battleShip[4] = computerPoint2 + 2;
                    battleShip[5] = computerPoint2 + 3;
                }


        }
        else{                                           //vertical
            computerPoint1 = rand() % 7;
            computerPoint2 = rand() % 10;
            for (int z = computerPoint1; z < computerPoint1 + 3; z++){
                if (setUp[z][computerPoint2] == 'O'){
                    overLapCheck = 1;
                }
                else{
                    overLapCheck = 2;
                    break;
                }
            }
                if (overLapCheck == 1){
                    setUp[computerPoint1][computerPoint2] = 'A';
                    setUp[computerPoint1 + 1][computerPoint2] = 'A';
                    setUp[computerPoint1 + 2][computerPoint2] = 'A';
                    setUp[computerPoint1 + 3][computerPoint2] = 'A';
                    battleShip[0] = computerShipDirection;
                    battleShip[1] = computerPoint2;
                    battleShip[2] = computerPoint1;
                    battleShip[3] = computerPoint1 + 1;
                    battleShip[4] = computerPoint1 + 2;
                    battleShip[5] = computerPoint1 + 3;
                }


        }

    } while (overLapCheck == 2);
    //Cruiser
    do{
        computerShipDirection = rand() % 2 + 1;
        if (computerShipDirection == 1){                //horizontal
            computerPoint1 = rand() % 10;
            computerPoint2 = rand() % 8;
            for (int z = computerPoint2; z < computerPoint2 + 2; z++){
                if (setUp[computerPoint1][z] == 'O'){
                    overLapCheck = 1;
                }
                else{
                    overLapCheck = 2;
                    break;
                }
            }
                if (overLapCheck == 1){
                    setUp[computerPoint1][computerPoint2] = 'A';
                    setUp[computerPoint1][computerPoint2 + 1] = 'A';
                    setUp[computerPoint1][computerPoint2 + 2] = 'A';
                    cruiser[0] = computerShipDirection;
                    cruiser[1] = computerPoint1;
                    cruiser[2] = computerPoint2;
                    cruiser[3] = computerPoint2 + 1;
                    cruiser[4] = computerPoint2 + 2;
                }


        }
        else{                                           //vertical
            computerPoint1 = rand() % 8;
            computerPoint2 = rand() % 10;
            for (int z = computerPoint1; z < computerPoint1 + 2; z++){
                if (setUp[z][computerPoint2] == 'O'){
                    overLapCheck = 1;
                }
                else{
                    overLapCheck = 2;
                    break;
                }
            }
    if (overLapCheck == 1){
        setUp[computerPoint1][computerPoint2] = 'A';
        setUp[computerPoint1 + 1][computerPoint2] = 'A';
        setUp[computerPoint1 + 2][computerPoint2] = 'A';
        cruiser[0] = computerShipDirection;
        cruiser[1] = computerPoint2;
        cruiser[2] = computerPoint1;
        cruiser[3] = computerPoint1 + 1;
        cruiser[4] = computerPoint1 + 2;
    }

        }
    } while (overLapCheck == 2);
    //submarine
    do{
        computerShipDirection = rand() % 2 + 1;
        if (computerShipDirection == 1){                //horizontal
            computerPoint1 = rand() % 10;
            computerPoint2 = rand() % 8;
            for (int z = computerPoint2; z < computerPoint2 + 2; z++){
                if (setUp[computerPoint1][z] == 'O'){
                    overLapCheck = 1;
                }
                else{
                    overLapCheck = 2;
                    break;
                }
            }
                if (overLapCheck == 1){
                    setUp[computerPoint1][computerPoint2] = 'A';
                    setUp[computerPoint1][computerPoint2 + 1] = 'A';
                    setUp[computerPoint1][computerPoint2 + 2] = 'A';
                    submarine[0] = computerShipDirection;
                    submarine[1] = computerPoint1;
                    submarine[2] = computerPoint2;
                    submarine[3] = computerPoint2 + 1;
                    submarine[4] = computerPoint2 + 2;
                }


        }
        else{                                           //vertical
            computerPoint1 = rand() % 8;
            computerPoint2 = rand() % 10;
            for (int z = computerPoint1; z < computerPoint1 + 2; z++){
                if (setUp[z][computerPoint2] == 'O'){
                    overLapCheck = 1;
                }
                else{
                    overLapCheck = 2;
                    break;
                }
            }
                if (overLapCheck == 1){
                    setUp[computerPoint1][computerPoint2] = 'A';
                    setUp[computerPoint1 + 1][computerPoint2] = 'A';
                    setUp[computerPoint1 + 2][computerPoint2] = 'A';
                    submarine[0] = computerShipDirection;
                    submarine[1] = computerPoint2;
                    submarine[2] = computerPoint1;
                    submarine[3] = computerPoint1 + 1;
                    submarine[4] = computerPoint1 + 2;
                }

        }
    } while (overLapCheck == 2);
    //patrol
    do{
        computerShipDirection = rand() % 2 + 1;
        if (computerShipDirection == 1){                //horizontal
            computerPoint1 = rand() % 10;
            computerPoint2 = rand() % 9;
            for (int z = computerPoint2; z < computerPoint2 + 1; z++){
                if (setUp[computerPoint1][z] == 'O'){
                    overLapCheck = 1;
                }
                else{
                    overLapCheck = 2;
                    break;
                }
            }
                if (overLapCheck == 1){
                    setUp[computerPoint1][computerPoint2] = 'A';
                    setUp[computerPoint1][computerPoint2 + 1] = 'A';
                    patrol[0] = computerShipDirection;
                    patrol[1] = computerPoint1;
                    patrol[2] = computerPoint2;
                    patrol[3] = computerPoint2 + 1;
                }


        }
        else{                                           //vertical
            computerPoint1 = rand() % 9;
            computerPoint2 = rand() % 10;
            for (int z = computerPoint1; z < computerPoint1 + 1; z++){
                if (setUp[z][computerPoint2] == 'O'){
                    overLapCheck = 1;
                }
                else{
                    overLapCheck = 2;
                    break;
                }
            }
                if (overLapCheck == 1){
                    setUp[computerPoint1][computerPoint2] = 'A';
                    setUp[computerPoint1 + 1][computerPoint2] = 'A';
                    patrol[0] = computerShipDirection;
                    patrol[1] = computerPoint2;
                    patrol[2] = computerPoint1;
                    patrol[3] = computerPoint1 + 1;
                }

        }
    } while (overLapCheck == 2);
}
//This function displays a scoreboard and displays ships that are alive or have been destroyed
void displayScoreBoard(HANDLE screen, char playerBoard[][COLS], char enemyBoard[][COLS], int rows, int enemyCarrier[], int enemyBattleShip[], int enemyCruiser[], int enemySubmarine[], int enemyPatrol[], int& enemyCarrierAlive, int& enemyBattleShipAlive, int& enemyCruiserAlive, int& enemySubmarineAlive, int& enemyPatrolAlive, int& playerCarrierAlive, int& playerBattleShipAlive, int& playerCruiserAlive, int& playerSubmarineAlive, int& playerPatrolAlive, int playerCarrier[], int playerBattleShip[], int playerCruiser[], int playerSubmarine[], int playerPatrol[]){

    int size;
    int alive;

    placeCursor(screen, 0, 38);
    cout << "-----Scoreboard-----" << endl; //1 = horizontal 2 = vertical
                                            //Enemy Ships
    placeCursor(screen, 2, 30);
    cout << "Enemy Ships Left: " << endl;
    placeCursor(screen, 3, 30);
    size = 7;
    alive = shipCheck(enemyBoard, ROWS, enemyCarrier, size);
    if (alive == 1){
        cout << "Carrier " << endl;
        enemyCarrierAlive = 1;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Carrier Destroyed!" << endl;
        enemyCarrierAlive = 0;
    }
    placeCursor(screen, 4, 30);
    size = 6;
    alive = shipCheck(enemyBoard, ROWS, enemyBattleShip, size);
    if (alive == 1){
        cout << "Battle Ship " << endl;
        enemyBattleShipAlive = 1;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Battle Ship Destroyed!" << endl;
        enemyBattleShipAlive = 0;
    }
    placeCursor(screen, 5, 30);
    size = 5;
    alive = shipCheck(enemyBoard, ROWS, enemyCruiser, size);
    if (alive == 1){
        cout << "Cruiser " << endl;
        enemyCruiserAlive = 1;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Cruiser Destroyed!" << endl;
        enemyCruiserAlive = 0;
    }
    placeCursor(screen, 6, 30);
    size = 5;
    alive = shipCheck(enemyBoard, ROWS, enemySubmarine, size);
    if (alive == 1){
        cout << "Submarine " << endl;
        enemySubmarineAlive = 1;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Submarine Destroyed!" << endl;
        enemySubmarineAlive = 0;
    }
    placeCursor(screen, 7, 30);
    size = 4;
    alive = shipCheck(enemyBoard, ROWS, enemyPatrol, size);
    if (alive == 1){
        cout << "Patrol " << endl;
        enemyPatrolAlive = 1;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Patrol Destroyed!" << endl;
        enemyPatrolAlive = 0;
    }
                                            //Player Ships
    placeCursor(screen, 2, 53);
    cout << "Your Ships Left:" << endl;
    placeCursor(screen, 3, 53);
    size = 7;
    alive = shipCheck(playerBoard, ROWS, playerCarrier, size);
    if (alive == 1){
        cout << "Carrier" << endl;
        playerCarrierAlive = 1;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Carrier Destroyed!" << endl;
        playerCarrierAlive = 0;
    }
    placeCursor(screen, 4, 53);
    size = 6;
    alive = shipCheck(playerBoard, ROWS, playerBattleShip, size);
    if (alive == 1){
        cout << "Battle Ship" << endl;
        playerBattleShipAlive = 1;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Battle Ship Destroyed!" << endl;
        playerBattleShipAlive = 0;
    }
    placeCursor(screen, 5, 53);
    size = 5;
    alive = shipCheck(playerBoard, ROWS, playerCruiser, size);
    if (alive == 1){
        cout << "Cruiser" << endl;
        playerCruiserAlive = 1;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Cruiser Destroyed!" << endl;
        playerCruiserAlive = 0;
    }
    placeCursor(screen, 6, 53);
    size = 5;
    alive = shipCheck(playerBoard, ROWS, playerSubmarine, size);
    if (alive == 1){
        cout << "Submarine" << endl;
        playerSubmarineAlive = 1;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Submarine Destroyed!" << endl;
        playerSubmarineAlive = 0;
    }
    placeCursor(screen, 7, 53);
    size = 4;
    alive = shipCheck(playerBoard, ROWS, playerPatrol, size);
    if (alive == 1){
        cout << "Patrol" << endl;
        playerPatrolAlive = 1;
    }
    else{
        cout << "Patrol Destroyed!" << endl;
        playerPatrolAlive = 0;
    }
}
//This function places the cursor on the screen in a specific location
void placeCursor(HANDLE screen, int row, int col){
    COORD position;
    position.Y = row;
    position.X = col;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, position);
}
//This function lets the player shoot at a point
void playerTurn(HANDLE screen, char enemyMap[][COLS], char enemyDisplayMap[][COLS], int rows) {
    //char v;
    string attack;
    int attack1, attack2, errorCount = 0;
    char holder;
    placeCursor(screen, 15, 30);
    cout << "Choose which point you would like to attack." << endl;
    stringInputCheck(screen, attack, attack1, attack2, 16, 30);
    holder = enemyMap[attack1][attack2];
    while (holder == 'M' || holder == 'X'){
        placeCursor(screen, 13, 30);
        cout << "You already attacked there!" << endl;
        placeCursor(screen, 17, 30);
        cout << "                    " << endl;
        stringInputCheck(screen, attack, attack1, attack2, 16, 30);
        holder = enemyMap[attack1][attack2];
    }
    if (holder == 'A'){
        enemyMap[attack1][attack2] = 'X';
        enemyDisplayMap[attack1][attack2] = 'X';
        system("CLS");
        placeCursor(screen, 23, 30);
        cout << "Direct hit!" << endl;
    }
    else{
        enemyMap[attack1][attack2] = 'M';
        enemyDisplayMap[attack1][attack2] = 'M';
        system("CLS");
        placeCursor(screen, 23, 30);
        cout << "You missed!" << endl;
    }
}
//This function lets the computer shoot at a point
void enemyTurn(HANDLE screen, char playerMap[][COLS], int rows, int difficulty){
    //AI                                                functions that lets the computer have its turn
    srand(time(0));
    //Computer(Medium);
    static char computerLastAttack1, computerLastAttack2, computerMemory = 'O';
    int computerAttack1, computerAttack2, computerNewAttack1, computerNewAttack2;
    char computerHolder;
    if (difficulty == 2){
        if (computerMemory == 'O'){
            computerAttack1 = rand() % 10;
            computerAttack2 = rand() % 10;
            computerHolder = playerMap[computerAttack1][computerAttack2];
            while (computerHolder == 'M' || computerHolder == 'X'){
                computerAttack1 = rand() % 10;
                computerAttack2 = rand() % 10;
                computerHolder = playerMap[computerAttack1][computerAttack2];
            }
            if (computerHolder == 'A'){
                playerMap[computerAttack1][computerAttack2] = 'X';
                placeCursor(screen, 24, 30);
                cout << "Computer(Medium) got a Direct hit!" << endl;
            }
            else{
                playerMap[computerAttack1][computerAttack2] = 'M';
                placeCursor(screen, 24, 30);
                cout << "Computer(Medium) missed!" << endl;
            }
            computerLastAttack1 = computerAttack1;
            computerLastAttack2 = computerAttack2;
            computerMemory = computerHolder;
        }
        //Computer Logic
        else{
            //Top Left Corner
            if (computerLastAttack1 == 0 && computerLastAttack2 == 0){
                computerNewAttack1 = computerLastAttack1;
                computerNewAttack2 = computerLastAttack2 + 1;
                computerHolder = playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2];
                if (computerHolder == 'M' || computerHolder == 'X'){
                    computerNewAttack1 = computerLastAttack1 + 1;
                    computerNewAttack2 = computerLastAttack2 - 1;
                    computerHolder = playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2];
                }
                while (computerHolder == 'M' || computerHolder == 'X'){
                    computerNewAttack1 = rand() % 10;
                    computerNewAttack2 = rand() % 10;
                    computerHolder = playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2];
                }
                if (computerHolder == 'A'){
                    playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2] = 'X';
                    placeCursor(screen, 24, 30);
                    cout << "Computer(Medium) got a Direct hit!" << endl;
                }
                else{
                    playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2] = 'M';
                    placeCursor(screen, 24, 30);
                    cout << "Computer(Medium) missed!" << endl;
                }
            }
            //Bottom Right Corner
            else if (computerLastAttack1 == 9 && computerLastAttack2 == 9){
                computerNewAttack1 = computerLastAttack1;
                computerNewAttack2 = computerLastAttack2 - 1;
                computerHolder = playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2];
                if (computerHolder == 'M' || computerHolder == 'X'){
                    computerNewAttack1 = computerLastAttack1 - 1;
                    computerNewAttack2 = computerLastAttack2 + 1;
                    computerHolder = playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2];
                }
                while (computerHolder == 'M' || computerHolder == 'X'){
                    computerNewAttack1 = rand() % 10;
                    computerNewAttack2 = rand() % 10;
                    computerHolder = playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2];
                }
                if (computerHolder == 'A'){
                    playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2] = 'X';
                    placeCursor(screen, 24, 30);
                    cout << "Computer(Medium) got a Direct hit!" << endl;
                }
                else{
                    playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2] = 'M';
                    placeCursor(screen, 24, 30);
                    cout << "Computer(Medium) missed!" << endl;
                }
            }
            //Top Right Corner
            else if (computerLastAttack1 == 0 && computerLastAttack2 == 9){
                computerNewAttack1 = computerLastAttack1;
                computerNewAttack2 = computerLastAttack2 - 1;
                computerHolder = playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2];
                if (computerHolder == 'M' || computerHolder == 'X'){
                    computerNewAttack1 = computerLastAttack1 + 1;
                    computerNewAttack2 = computerLastAttack2 + 1;
                    computerHolder = playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2];
                }
                while (computerHolder == 'M' || computerHolder == 'X'){
                    computerNewAttack1 = rand() % 10;
                    computerNewAttack2 = rand() % 10;
                    computerHolder = playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2];
                }
                if (computerHolder == 'A'){
                    playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2] = 'X';
                    placeCursor(screen, 24, 30);
                    cout << "Computer(Medium) got a Direct hit!" << endl;
                }
                else{
                    playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2] = 'M';
                    placeCursor(screen, 24, 30);
                    cout << "Computer(Medium) missed!" << endl;
                }
            }
            //Bottom Left Corner
            else if (computerLastAttack1 == 9 && computerLastAttack2 == 0){
                computerNewAttack1 = computerLastAttack1;
                computerNewAttack2 = computerLastAttack2 + 1;
                computerHolder = playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2];
                if (computerHolder == 'M' || computerHolder == 'X'){
                    computerNewAttack1 = computerLastAttack1 - 1;
                    computerNewAttack2 = computerLastAttack2 - 1;
                    computerHolder = playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2];
                }
                while (computerHolder == 'M' || computerHolder == 'X'){
                    computerNewAttack1 = rand() % 10;
                    computerNewAttack2 = rand() % 10;
                    computerHolder = playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2];
                }
                if (computerHolder == 'A'){
                    playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2] = 'X';
                    placeCursor(screen, 24, 30);
                    cout << "Computer(Medium) got a Direct hit!" << endl;
                }
                else{
                    playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2] = 'M';
                    placeCursor(screen, 24, 30);
                    cout << "Computer(Medium) missed!" << endl;
                }
            }
            //Top Wall
            else if (computerLastAttack1 == 0){
                if (computerLastAttack2 == 9){
                    computerNewAttack1 = computerLastAttack1;
                    computerNewAttack2 = computerLastAttack2 - 1;
                }
                else{
                    computerNewAttack1 = computerLastAttack1;
                    computerNewAttack2 = computerLastAttack2 + 1;
                }
                computerHolder = playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2];
                if (computerHolder == 'M' || computerHolder == 'X'){
                    computerNewAttack1 = computerLastAttack1 + 1;
                    computerNewAttack2 = computerLastAttack2;
                    computerHolder = playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2];
                }
                while (computerHolder == 'M' || computerHolder == 'X'){
                    computerNewAttack1 = rand() % 10;
                    computerNewAttack2 = rand() % 10;
                    computerHolder = playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2];
                }
                if (computerHolder == 'A'){
                    playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2] = 'X';
                    placeCursor(screen, 24, 30);
                    cout << "Computer(Medium) got a Direct hit!" << endl;
                }
                else{
                    playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2] = 'M';
                    placeCursor(screen, 24, 30);
                    cout << "Computer(Medium) missed!" << endl;
                }
            }
            //Left Wall
            else if (computerLastAttack2 == 0){
                if (computerLastAttack1 == 9){
                    computerNewAttack1 = computerLastAttack1 - 1;
                    computerNewAttack2 = computerLastAttack2;
                }
                else{
                    computerNewAttack1 = computerLastAttack1 + 1;
                    computerNewAttack2 = computerLastAttack2;
                }
                computerHolder = playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2];
                if (computerHolder == 'M' || computerHolder == 'X'){
                    computerNewAttack1 = computerLastAttack1;
                    computerNewAttack2 = computerLastAttack2 + 1;
                    computerHolder = playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2];
                }
                while (computerHolder == 'M' || computerHolder == 'X'){
                    computerNewAttack1 = rand() % 10;
                    computerNewAttack2 = rand() % 10;
                    computerHolder = playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2];
                }
                if (computerHolder == 'A'){
                    playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2] = 'X';
                    placeCursor(screen, 24, 30);
                    cout << "Computer(Medium) got a Direct hit!" << endl;
                }
                else{
                    playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2] = 'M';
                    placeCursor(screen, 24, 30);
                    cout << "Computer(Medium) missed!" << endl;
                }
            }
            //Right Wall
            else if (computerLastAttack2 == 9){
                if (computerLastAttack1 == 8){
                    computerNewAttack1 = computerLastAttack1 - 1;
                    computerNewAttack2 = computerLastAttack2;
                }
                else{
                    computerNewAttack1 = computerLastAttack1 + 1;
                    computerNewAttack2 = computerLastAttack2;
                }
                computerHolder = playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2];
                if (computerHolder == 'M' || computerHolder == 'X'){
                    computerNewAttack1 = computerLastAttack1;
                    computerNewAttack2 = computerLastAttack2 - 1;
                    computerHolder = playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2];
                }
                while (computerHolder == 'M' || computerHolder == 'X'){
                    computerNewAttack1 = rand() % 10;
                    computerNewAttack2 = rand() % 10;
                    computerHolder = playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2];
                }
                if (computerHolder == 'A'){
                    playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2] = 'X';
                    placeCursor(screen, 24, 30);
                    cout << "Computer(Medium) got a Direct hit!" << endl;
                }
                else{
                    playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2] = 'M';
                    placeCursor(screen, 24, 30);
                    cout << "Computer(Medium) missed!" << endl;
                }
            }
            //Bottom Wall
            else if (computerLastAttack1 == 9){
                if (computerLastAttack2 == 8){
                    computerNewAttack1 = computerLastAttack1;
                    computerNewAttack2 = computerLastAttack2 - 1;
                }
                else{
                    computerNewAttack1 = computerLastAttack1;
                    computerNewAttack2 = computerLastAttack2 + 1;
                }
                computerHolder = playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2];
                if (computerHolder == 'M' || computerHolder == 'X'){
                    computerNewAttack1 = computerLastAttack1 - 1;
                    computerNewAttack2 = computerLastAttack2;
                    computerHolder = playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2];
                }
                while (computerHolder == 'M' || computerHolder == 'X'){
                    computerNewAttack1 = rand() % 10;
                    computerNewAttack2 = rand() % 10;
                    computerHolder = playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2];
                }
                if (computerHolder == 'A'){
                    playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2] = 'X';
                    placeCursor(screen, 24, 30);
                    cout << "Computer(Medium) got a Direct hit!" << endl;
                }
                else{
                    playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2] = 'M';
                    placeCursor(screen, 24, 30);
                    cout << "Computer(Medium) missed!" << endl;
                }
            }
            //anywhere else on map
            else{
                computerNewAttack1 = computerLastAttack1;
                computerNewAttack2 = computerLastAttack2 + 1;
                computerHolder = playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2];
                if (computerHolder == 'M' || computerHolder == 'X'){
                    computerNewAttack1 = computerLastAttack1;
                    computerNewAttack2 = computerLastAttack2 - 1;
                    computerHolder = playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2];
                }
                else if (computerHolder == 'M' || computerHolder == 'X'){
                    computerNewAttack1 = computerLastAttack1 - 1;
                    computerNewAttack2 = computerLastAttack2;
                    computerHolder = playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2];
                }
                else if (computerHolder == 'M' || computerHolder == 'X'){
                    computerNewAttack1 = computerLastAttack1 + 1;
                    computerNewAttack2 = computerLastAttack2;
                    computerHolder = playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2];
                }
                while (computerHolder == 'M' || computerHolder == 'X'){
                    computerNewAttack1 = rand() % 10;
                    computerNewAttack2 = rand() % 10;
                    computerHolder = playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2];
                }
                if (computerHolder == 'A'){
                    playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2] = 'X';
                    placeCursor(screen, 24, 30);
                    cout << "Computer(Medium) got a Direct hit!" << endl;
                }
                else{
                    playerMap[computerNewAttack1][computerNewAttack2] = 'M';
                    placeCursor(screen, 24, 30);
                    cout << "Computer(Medium) missed!" << endl;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    //Computer(Easy);
    else{
        computerAttack1 = rand() % 10;
        computerAttack2 = rand() % 10;
        computerHolder = playerMap[computerAttack1][computerAttack2];
        while (computerHolder == 'M' || computerHolder == 'X'){
            computerAttack1 = rand() % 10;
            computerAttack2 = rand() % 10;
            computerHolder = playerMap[computerAttack1][computerAttack2];
        }
        if (computerHolder == 'A'){
            playerMap[computerAttack1][computerAttack2] = 'X';
            placeCursor(screen, 24, 30);
            cout << "Computer(Easy) got a Direct hit!" << endl;
        }
        else{
            playerMap[computerAttack1][computerAttack2] = 'M';
            placeCursor(screen, 24, 30);
            cout << "Computer(Easy) missed!" << endl;
        }
    }

}
//This function checks if there are any ships left
int winCondition(int enemy, int player){

    if (enemy == 0){
        return 2;
    }
    else if (player == 0){
        return 3;
    }
    else{
        return 1;
    }
}
//outdated functions

//This function checks if the letter entered by the user is valid
//int letterVal(char c){
//  int attack;
//  if (!(c == 'A' || c == 'a' || c == 'B' || c == 'b' || c == 'C' || c == 'c' || c == 'D' || c == 'd' || c == 'E' || c == 'e' || c == 'F' || c == 'f' || c == 'G' || c == 'g' || c == 'H' || c == 'h' || c == 'I' || c == 'i' || c == 'J' || c == 'j')){
//      do
//      {
//          cin.clear();
//          cout << "Invalid input, please enter a letter that is from A-J: ";
//          cin.get(c);
//      } while (!(c == 'A' || c == 'a' || c == 'B' || c == 'b' || c == 'C' || c == 'c' || c == 'D' || c == 'd' || c == 'E' || c == 'e' || c == 'F' || c == 'f' || c == 'G' || c == 'g' || c == 'H' || c == 'h' || c == 'I' || c == 'i' || c == 'J' || c == 'j'));
//  }
//  if (c == 'A' || c == 'a')
//      attack = 0;
//  else if (c == 'B' || c == 'b')
//      attack = 1;
//  else if (c == 'C' || c == 'c')
//      attack = 2;
//  else if (c == 'D' || c == 'd')
//      attack = 3;
//  else if (c == 'E' || c == 'e')
//      attack = 4;
//  else if (c == 'F' || c == 'f')
//      attack = 5;
//  else if (c == 'G' || c == 'g')
//      attack = 6;
//  else if (c == 'H' || c == 'h')
//      attack = 7;
//  else if (c == 'I' || c == 'i')
//      attack = 8;
//  else if (c == 'J' || c == 'j')
//      attack = 9;
//  return attack;
//}
//This function checks if the number entered by the user is valid
//int numValidation(int z){
//  if (cin.fail() || z < 0 || z > 9){
//      do{
//          cin.clear();
//          cout << "Invalid input. Please enter a number 0-9: ";
//          cin >> z;
//      } while (cin.fail());
//  }
//  return z;
//}

//This function checks which ships are alive or dead when called                
int shipCheck(char board[][COLS], int rows, int ship[], int size){

    int holder;

    if (ship[0] == 1){
        for (int x = 2; x < size; x++){     
            if(board[ship[1]][ship[x]] == 'A'){
                holder = 1;
                break;
            }
            else{
                holder = 2;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        for (int x = 2; x < size; x++){
            if (board[ship[x]][ship[1]] == 'A'){
                holder = 1;
                break;
            }
            else{
                holder = 2;
            }
        }
    }
    return holder;
}
//This function validates the player choice of where to attack
void stringInputCheck(HANDLE screen, string attack, int &attack1, int &attack2, int row, int col){

  int errorCount = 0;

    do{
        if (errorCount > 0){
            placeCursor(screen, row + 1, col);
            cout << "                       " << endl;
        }
        placeCursor(screen, row, col);
        cout << "Please type the letter first followed by" << endl;
        placeCursor(screen, row + 1, col);
        cout << "the number: ";
        cin.ignore();
        cin >> attack;
        errorCount++;
    } while (!(attack == "a0" || attack == "a1" || attack == "a2" || attack == "a3" || attack == "a4" || attack == "a5" || attack == "a6" || attack == "a7" || attack == "a8" || attack == "a9" || attack == "b0" || attack == "b1" || attack == "b2" || attack == "b3" || attack == "b4" || attack == "b5" || attack == "b6" || attack == "b7" || attack == "b8" || attack == "b9" || attack == "c0" || attack == "c1" || attack == "c2" || attack == "c3" || attack == "c4" || attack == "c5" || attack == "c6" || attack == "c7" || attack == "c8" || attack == "c9" || attack == "d0" || attack == "d1" || attack == "d2" || attack == "d3" || attack == "d4" || attack == "d5" || attack == "d6" || attack == "d7" || attack == "d8" || attack == "d9" || attack == "e0" || attack == "e1" || attack == "e2" || attack == "e3" || attack == "e4" || attack == "e5" || attack == "e6" || attack == "e7" || attack == "e8" || attack == "e9" || attack == "f0" || attack == "f1" || attack == "f2" || attack == "f3" || attack == "f4" || attack == "f5" || attack == "f6" || attack == "f7" || attack == "f8" || attack == "f9" || attack == "g0" || attack == "g1" || attack == "g2" || attack == "g3" || attack == "g4" || attack == "g5" || attack == "g6" || attack == "g7" || attack == "g8" || attack == "g9" || attack == "h0" || attack == "h1" || attack == "h2" || attack == "h3" || attack == "h4" || attack == "h5" || attack == "h6" || attack == "h7" || attack == "h8" || attack == "h9" || attack == "i0" || attack == "i1" || attack == "i2" || attack == "i3" || attack == "i4" || attack == "i5" || attack == "i6" || attack == "i7" || attack == "i8" || attack == "i9" || attack == "j0" || attack == "j1" || attack == "j2" || attack == "j3" || attack == "j4" || attack == "j5" || attack == "j6" || attack == "j7" || attack == "j8" || attack == "j9"));

    if (attack == "a0"){
        attack1 = 0;
        attack2 = 0;
    }
    if (attack == "a1"){
        attack1 = 0;
        attack2 = 1;
    }
    if (attack == "a2"){
        attack1 = 0;
        attack2 = 2;
    }
    if (attack == "a3"){
        attack1 = 0;
        attack2 = 3;
    }
    if (attack == "a4"){
        attack1 = 0;
        attack2 = 4;
    }
    if (attack == "a5"){
        attack1 = 0;
        attack2 = 5;
    }
    if (attack == "a6"){
        attack1 = 0;
        attack2 = 6;
    }
    if (attack == "a7"){
        attack1 = 0;
        attack2 = 7;
    }
    if (attack == "a8"){
        attack1 = 0;
        attack2 = 8;
    }
    if (attack == "a9"){
        attack1 = 0;
        attack2 = 9;
    }
    if (attack == "b0"){
        attack1 = 1;
        attack2 = 0;
    }
    if (attack == "b1"){
        attack1 = 1;
        attack2 = 1;
    }
    if (attack == "b2"){
        attack1 = 1;
        attack2 = 2;
    }
    if (attack == "b3"){
        attack1 = 1;
        attack2 = 3;
    }
    if (attack == "b4"){
        attack1 = 1;
        attack2 = 4;
    }
    if (attack == "b5"){
        attack1 = 1;
        attack2 = 5;
    }
    if (attack == "b6"){
        attack1 = 1;
        attack2 = 6;
    }
    if (attack == "b7"){
        attack1 = 1;
        attack2 = 7;
    }
    if (attack == "b8"){
        attack1 = 1;
        attack2 = 8;
    }
    if (attack == "b9"){
        attack1 = 1;
        attack2 = 9;
    }
    if (attack == "c0"){
        attack1 = 2;
        attack2 = 0;
    }
    if (attack == "c1"){
        attack1 = 2;
        attack2 = 1;
    }
    if (attack == "c2"){
        attack1 = 2;
        attack2 = 2;
    }
    if (attack == "c3"){
        attack1 = 2;
        attack2 = 3;
    }
    if (attack == "c4"){
        attack1 = 2;
        attack2 = 4;
    }
    if (attack == "c5"){
        attack1 = 2;
        attack2 = 5;
    }
    if (attack == "c6"){
        attack1 = 2;
        attack2 = 6;
    }
    if (attack == "c7"){
        attack1 = 2;
        attack2 = 7;
    }
    if (attack == "c8"){
        attack1 = 2;
        attack2 = 8;
    }
    if (attack == "c9"){
        attack1 = 2;
        attack2 = 9;
    }
    if (attack == "d0"){
        attack1 = 3;
        attack2 = 0;
    }
    if (attack == "d1"){
        attack1 = 3;
        attack2 = 1;
    }
    if (attack == "d2"){
        attack1 = 3;
        attack2 = 2;
    }
    if (attack == "d3"){
        attack1 = 3;
        attack2 = 3;
    }
    if (attack == "d4"){
        attack1 = 3;
        attack2 = 4;
    }
    if (attack == "d5"){
        attack1 = 3;
        attack2 = 5;
    }
    if (attack == "d6"){
        attack1 = 3;
        attack2 = 6;
    }
    if (attack == "d7"){
        attack1 = 3;
        attack2 = 7;
    }
    if (attack == "d8"){
        attack1 = 3;
        attack2 = 8;
    }
    if (attack == "d9"){
        attack1 = 3;
        attack2 = 9;
    }
    if (attack == "e0"){
        attack1 = 4;
        attack2 = 0;
    }
    if (attack == "e1"){
        attack1 = 4;
        attack2 = 1;
    }
    if (attack == "e2"){
        attack1 = 4;
        attack2 = 2;
    }
    if (attack == "e3"){
        attack1 = 4;
        attack2 = 3;
    }
    if (attack == "e4"){
        attack1 = 4;
        attack2 = 4;
    }
    if (attack == "e5"){
        attack1 = 4;
        attack2 = 5;
    }
    if (attack == "e6"){
        attack1 = 4;
        attack2 = 6;
    }
    if (attack == "e7"){
        attack1 = 4;
        attack2 = 7;
    }
    if (attack == "e8"){
        attack1 = 4;
        attack2 = 8;
    }
    if (attack == "e9"){
        attack1 = 4;
        attack2 = 9;
    }
    if (attack == "f0"){
        attack1 = 5;
        attack2 = 0;
    }
    if (attack == "f1"){
        attack1 = 5;
        attack2 = 1;
    }
    if (attack == "f2"){
        attack1 = 5;
        attack2 = 2;
    }
    if (attack == "f3"){
        attack1 = 5;
        attack2 = 3;
    }
    if (attack == "f4"){
        attack1 = 5;
        attack2 = 4;
    }
    if (attack == "f5"){
        attack1 = 5;
        attack2 = 5;
    }
    if (attack == "f6"){
        attack1 = 5;
        attack2 = 6;
    }
    if (attack == "f7"){
        attack1 = 5;
        attack2 = 7;
    }
    if (attack == "f8"){
        attack1 = 5;
        attack2 = 8;
    }
    if (attack == "f9"){
        attack1 = 5;
        attack2 = 9;
    }
    if (attack == "g0"){
        attack1 = 6;
        attack2 = 0;
    }
    if (attack == "g1"){
        attack1 = 6;
        attack2 = 1;
    }
    if (attack == "g2"){
        attack1 = 6;
        attack2 = 2;
    }
    if (attack == "g3"){
        attack1 = 6;
        attack2 = 3;
    }
    if (attack == "g4"){
        attack1 = 6;
        attack2 = 4;
    }
    if (attack == "g5"){
        attack1 = 6;
        attack2 = 5;
    }
    if (attack == "g6"){
        attack1 = 6;
        attack2 = 6;
    }
    if (attack == "g7"){
        attack1 = 6;
        attack2 = 7;
    }
    if (attack == "g8"){
        attack1 = 6;
        attack2 = 8;
    }
    if (attack == "g9"){
        attack1 = 6;
        attack2 = 9;
    }
    if (attack == "h0"){
        attack1 = 7;
        attack2 = 0;
    }
    if (attack == "h1"){
        attack1 = 7;
        attack2 = 1;
    }
    if (attack == "h2"){
        attack1 = 7;
        attack2 = 2;
    }
    if (attack == "h3"){
        attack1 = 7;
        attack2 = 3;
    }
    if (attack == "h4"){
        attack1 = 7;
        attack2 = 4;
    }
    if (attack == "h5"){
        attack1 = 7;
        attack2 = 5;
    }
    if (attack == "h6"){
        attack1 = 7;
        attack2 = 6;
    }
    if (attack == "h7"){
        attack1 = 7;
        attack2 = 7;
    }
    if (attack == "h8"){
        attack1 = 7;
        attack2 = 8;
    }
    if (attack == "h9"){
        attack1 = 7;
        attack2 = 9;
    }
    if (attack == "i0"){
        attack1 = 8;
        attack2 = 0;
    }
    if (attack == "i1"){
        attack1 = 8;
        attack2 = 1;
    }
    if (attack == "i2"){
        attack1 = 8;
        attack2 = 2;
    }
    if (attack == "i3"){
        attack1 = 8;
        attack2 = 3;
    }
    if (attack == "i4"){
        attack1 = 8;
        attack2 = 4;
    }
    if (attack == "i5"){
        attack1 = 8;
        attack2 = 5;
    }
    if (attack == "i6"){
        attack1 = 8;
        attack2 = 6;
    }
    if (attack == "i7"){
        attack1 = 8;
        attack2 = 7;
    }
    if (attack == "i8"){
        attack1 = 8;
        attack2 = 8;
    }
    if (attack == "i9"){
        attack1 = 8;
        attack2 = 9;
    }
    if (attack == "j0"){
        attack1 = 9;
        attack2 = 0;
    }
    if (attack == "j1"){
        attack1 = 9;
        attack2 = 1;
    }
    if (attack == "j2"){
        attack1 = 9;
        attack2 = 2;
    }
    if (attack == "j3"){
        attack1 = 9;
        attack2 = 3;
    }
    if (attack == "j4"){
        attack1 = 9;
        attack2 = 4;
    }
    if (attack == "j5"){
        attack1 = 9;
        attack2 = 5;
    }
    if (attack == "j6"){
        attack1 = 9;
        attack2 = 6;
    }
    if (attack == "j7"){
        attack1 = 9;
        attack2 = 7;
    }
    if (attack == "j8"){
        attack1 = 9;
        attack2 = 8;
    }
    if (attack == "j9"){
        attack1 = 9;
        attack2 = 9;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's just some observations about coding and design:

1. Instead of A, B, C choices, try S for start and Q to quit.  This way people don't have to mentally "translate" the choice.
2. At the beginning, you ask them to choose A, B, or C.  But what is option C?  Probably a copy/paste from further down.
3. Use a `tolower(choice)` and only compare a, b, or c and remove the uppercase checks.
4. I have mixed emotions about putting in "under construction" references.  If it's not ready, why put it in?  But then again, it may want me to purchase the update to the program.
5. Instead of the big "if tower" for the alphabet, try `cout << (char)(x+65)`.  A `(char)65` displays an A, `(char)66` a B, etc.

Comment: 5: That presumes ASCII-based, but it's fairly unlikely to ever run on an EBCDIC big-iron, even with considerable work elsewhere. You could also mention `switch`...

Answer (score 4):

I'd give you tips about your code, but it's over my head. I did play a round with it though, and here's a list of things I noticed that could be better about the design.

- It was really hard to tell if shots hit or missed. I would add some text to the right that says "Hit", "Miss", "Battleship sunk", etc. after every turn
- I know that it makes sense from the code side, but it felt weird playing from 0 to 9 instead of from 1 to 10.
- For one of my turns the game said that all of the computer's ships were sunk, but I had to shoot again before the game realized that I had won.
- It was annoying that the ships were all the same color *and* letter. I'd change the letters by ship, since I can't even tell where my ships are here (Also, isn't the background always black? Because I had trouble seeing the blue.)

[image: randomly generated board]

Comment: A good review, though less a code- than a design-review. A point to add: Better to accept row and column in any order, than to complicate instructions.

Comment: Two more things to add.   1) An extension of the first point - while it's much easier to tell if your opponent hit, it's still annoying trying to figure out whether they sunk your ship or not.   2) It would be much easier to play another round if you had it go back to the first screen after the game, or at least had a screen that asked if I want to play again.

Comment: You can [edit] your post to add that whenever you want. I mustn't.

Comment: It does say hit or miss under where is says "Choose which point..." It may have been cut off of the screen. It is under the function "void playerTurn". Was it not showing up on the screen?

Comment: Not that I saw, although I might have just missed it though.

Answer (score 3):

i have seen that you are using very often *magic numbers* like `gameOver == 1` insted of that you could use `const`s or `enum`s. in this case an enum would be good, because an `enum` shows the different status.

First you need to define the enum:

```
typedef enum
{
    Running,

    Paused,

    Won,

    Lost
} GameStatus;
```

This code is not that good readable, because you do not know when gameOver is 1 or 2 or whatever. Also when you debug your code you will just see a number as value.

**Old Code:**

```
do
{
    placeCursor(screen, 0, 0);                                     
    // ...
    gameOver = winCondition(enemyAlive, playerAlive);              
} 
while (gameOver == 1);
if (gameOver == 2)
{
    cout << "You Win!" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "You Lost!" << endl;
}
```

I changed the variable name of `gameOver` to `gameStatus`. The datatype changes to `GameStatus`. The code looks like this now, which is better readable.

**New Code:**

```
do
{
    placeCursor(screen, 0, 0);                                      
    // ...
    gameStatus = winCondition(enemyAlive, playerAlive);             
} 
while (gameStatus == GameStatus.Running);
if (gameStatus == GameStatus.Won)
{
    cout << "You Win!" << endl;
}
if (gameStatus == GameStatus.Lost)
{
    cout << "You Lost!" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `void stringInputCheck` method can be much more optimized. You have like **100** if checks in this method.

You want to read the input of the next attack with this method. for this the user should insert a char between 'a' and 'j' and a number between 0 and 9. So your input string can't be longer than 2.

The first thing i would do is defining a struct for the `Position`:

```
typedef struct
{
    int X;
    int Y;
} Position;
```

Now you are able to save the X and Y coordinate of the input in a field.

---

**Maybe skip this part or check the comments below.**

I would recommend to read the input as a char array, because i think it is easier as string. (but i am no c++ guy so i don't know how string works).

then the read of the input looks like this:

```
char attack[2];
cin >> attack;
```

---

Now you have read the X and Y value as a char. but you want it as a number.
If you look into e.g. a [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/) you can see that every char has a number. its like a mapping. So e.g. '0' as a char is 48 as a decimal.

So lets use this :)

---

First allocate memory for the Position object:

```
auto pos = new Position();
```

you can assign a value to this object on two ways:

```
(*pos).X = 0; or
pos->X = 0;
```

i would recommend the second way because the readability is much better!

don't forget to delete created object when you don'T need them anymore:

```
delete pos;
```

---

**Char To Number**
Lets assume the input is "B5".
The easier part to read is the '5'. So we will do this first.

```
pos->Y = attack[1] - '0';
```

what we are doing here is substracting the value of 0 which is in the ascii table 48 from `attack[1]` ('5') which is in the ascii table 53. So we are calculating:

```
53 - 48 = 5
```

And we are doing the same with the B. Look at this method (works for upper and lower case input):

```
int charToNumber(char character)
{
    int number = character - 'a';
    if(number > 0)
    {
        return number;
    }

    return character - 'A';
}
```

**Full solution:**

```
char attack[2];
cin >> attack;

Position* pos = (Position*)malloc(sizeof(Position));
pos->X = charToNumber(attack[0]);
pos->Y = attack[1] - '0';
```

Now you are able to check for correct ranges much more easily:

```
if(pos->X >= 0 && pos->X <= 9 &&
   pos->Y >= 0 && pos->Y <= 9)
{ ... }
```

Comment: That `char[2]` is a *terrible* idea: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2

Comment: We are in C++, so why do you use `malloc`?

Comment: @Deduplicator Because i have no C++ experience, but i know that `malloc`s works. would be great when you could provide a better solution. am i using the `new` keyword then?

Comment: Well, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc for how that could be improved, though part only applies to C. And in C++ you would use `auto p = new Position; delete p;`. (As in C always remember to use the proper cleanup-method for the allocation-method you used.)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (attack == "a0"){
    attack1 = 0;
    attack2 = 0;
}
if (attack == "a1"){
    attack1 = 0;
    attack2 = 1;
}
if (attack == "a2"){
    attack1 = 0;
    attack2 = 2;
}
if (attack == "a3"){
    attack1 = 0;
    attack2 = 3;
}
if (attack == "a4"){
    attack1 = 0;
    attack2 = 4;
}
if (attack == "a5"){
    attack1 = 0;
    attack2 = 5;
}
if (attack == "a6"){
    attack1 = 0;
    attack2 = 6;
}
if (attack == "a7"){
    attack1 = 0;
    attack2 = 7;
}
if (attack == "a8"){
    attack1 = 0;
    attack2 = 8;
}
if (attack == "a9"){
    attack1 = 0;
    attack2 = 9;
}
if (attack == "b0"){
    attack1 = 1;
    attack2 = 0;
}
if (attack == "b1"){
    attack1 = 1;
    attack2 = 1;
}
if (attack == "b2"){
    attack1 = 1;
    attack2 = 2;
}
if (attack == "b3"){
    attack1 = 1;
    attack2 = 3;
}
if (attack == "b4"){
    attack1 = 1;
    attack2 = 4;
}
if (attack == "b5"){
    attack1 = 1;
    attack2 = 5;
}
if (attack == "b6"){
    attack1 = 1;
    attack2 = 6;
}
if (attack == "b7"){
    attack1 = 1;
    attack2 = 7;
}
if (attack == "b8"){
    attack1 = 1;
    attack2 = 8;
}
if (attack == "b9"){
    attack1 = 1;
    attack2 = 9;
}
if (attack == "c0"){
    attack1 = 2;
    attack2 = 0;
}
if (attack == "c1"){
    attack1 = 2;
    attack2 = 1;
}
if (attack == "c2"){
    attack1 = 2;
    attack2 = 2;
}
if (attack == "c3"){
    attack1 = 2;
    attack2 = 3;
}
if (attack == "c4"){
    attack1 = 2;
    attack2 = 4;
}
if (attack == "c5"){
    attack1 = 2;
    attack2 = 5;
}
if (attack == "c6"){
    attack1 = 2;
    attack2 = 6;
}
if (attack == "c7"){
    attack1 = 2;
    attack2 = 7;
}
if (attack == "c8"){
    attack1 = 2;
    attack2 = 8;
}
if (attack == "c9"){
    attack1 = 2;
    attack2 = 9;
}
if (attack == "d0"){
    attack1 = 3;
    attack2 = 0;
}
if (attack == "d1"){
    attack1 = 3;
    attack2 = 1;
}
if (attack == "d2"){
    attack1 = 3;
    attack2 = 2;
}
if (attack == "d3"){
    attack1 = 3;
    attack2 = 3;
}
if (attack == "d4"){
    attack1 = 3;
    attack2 = 4;
}
if (attack == "d5"){
    attack1 = 3;
    attack2 = 5;
}
if (attack == "d6"){
    attack1 = 3;
    attack2 = 6;
}
if (attack == "d7"){
    attack1 = 3;
    attack2 = 7;
}
if (attack == "d8"){
    attack1 = 3;
    attack2 = 8;
}
if (attack == "d9"){
    attack1 = 3;
    attack2 = 9;
}
if (attack == "e0"){
    attack1 = 4;
    attack2 = 0;
}
if (attack == "e1"){
    attack1 = 4;
    attack2 = 1;
}
if (attack == "e2"){
    attack1 = 4;
    attack2 = 2;
}
if (attack == "e3"){
    attack1 = 4;
    attack2 = 3;
}
if (attack == "e4"){
    attack1 = 4;
    attack2 = 4;
}
if (attack == "e5"){
    attack1 = 4;
    attack2 = 5;
}
if (attack == "e6"){
    attack1 = 4;
    attack2 = 6;
}
if (attack == "e7"){
    attack1 = 4;
    attack2 = 7;
}
if (attack == "e8"){
    attack1 = 4;
    attack2 = 8;
}
if (attack == "e9"){
    attack1 = 4;
    attack2 = 9;
}
if (attack == "f0"){
    attack1 = 5;
    attack2 = 0;
}
if (attack == "f1"){
    attack1 = 5;
    attack2 = 1;
}
if (attack == "f2"){
    attack1 = 5;
    attack2 = 2;
}
if (attack == "f3"){
    attack1 = 5;
    attack2 = 3;
}
if (attack == "f4"){
    attack1 = 5;
    attack2 = 4;
}
if (attack == "f5"){
    attack1 = 5;
    attack2 = 5;
}
if (attack == "f6"){
    attack1 = 5;
    attack2 = 6;
}
if (attack == "f7"){
    attack1 = 5;
    attack2 = 7;
}
if (attack == "f8"){
    attack1 = 5;
    attack2 = 8;
}
if (attack == "f9"){
    attack1 = 5;
    attack2 = 9;
}
if (attack == "g0"){
    attack1 = 6;
    attack2 = 0;
}
if (attack == "g1"){
    attack1 = 6;
    attack2 = 1;
}
if (attack == "g2"){
    attack1 = 6;
    attack2 = 2;
}
if (attack == "g3"){
    attack1 = 6;
    attack2 = 3;
}
if (attack == "g4"){
    attack1 = 6;
    attack2 = 4;
}
if (attack == "g5"){
    attack1 = 6;
    attack2 = 5;
}
if (attack == "g6"){
    attack1 = 6;
    attack2 = 6;
}
if (attack == "g7"){
    attack1 = 6;
    attack2 = 7;
}
if (attack == "g8"){
    attack1 = 6;
    attack2 = 8;
}
if (attack == "g9"){
    attack1 = 6;
    attack2 = 9;
}
if (attack == "h0"){
    attack1 = 7;
    attack2 = 0;
}
if (attack == "h1"){
    attack1 = 7;
    attack2 = 1;
}
if (attack == "h2"){
    attack1 = 7;
    attack2 = 2;
}
if (attack == "h3"){
    attack1 = 7;
    attack2 = 3;
}
if (attack == "h4"){
    attack1 = 7;
    attack2 = 4;
}
if (attack == "h5"){
    attack1 = 7;
    attack2 = 5;
}
if (attack == "h6"){
    attack1 = 7;
    attack2 = 6;
}
if (attack == "h7"){
    attack1 = 7;
    attack2 = 7;
}
if (attack == "h8"){
    attack1 = 7;
    attack2 = 8;
}
if (attack == "h9"){
    attack1 = 7;
    attack2 = 9;
}
if (attack == "i0"){
    attack1 = 8;
    attack2 = 0;
}
if (attack == "i1"){
    attack1 = 8;
    attack2 = 1;
}
if (attack == "i2"){
    attack1 = 8;
    attack2 = 2;
}
if (attack == "i3"){
    attack1 = 8;
    attack2 = 3;
}
if (attack == "i4"){
    attack1 = 8;
    attack2 = 4;
}
if (attack == "i5"){
    attack1 = 8;
    attack2 = 5;
}
if (attack == "i6"){
    attack1 = 8;
    attack2 = 6;
}
if (attack == "i7"){
    attack1 = 8;
    attack2 = 7;
}
if (attack == "i8"){
    attack1 = 8;
    attack2 = 8;
}
if (attack == "i9"){
    attack1 = 8;
    attack2 = 9;
}
if (attack == "j0"){
    attack1 = 9;
    attack2 = 0;
}
if (attack == "j1"){
    attack1 = 9;
    attack2 = 1;
}
if (attack == "j2"){
    attack1 = 9;
    attack2 = 2;
}
if (attack == "j3"){
    attack1 = 9;
    attack2 = 3;
}
if (attack == "j4"){
    attack1 = 9;
    attack2 = 4;
}
if (attack == "j5"){
    attack1 = 9;
    attack2 = 5;
}
if (attack == "j6"){
    attack1 = 9;
    attack2 = 6;
}
if (attack == "j7"){
    attack1 = 9;
    attack2 = 7;
}
if (attack == "j8"){
    attack1 = 9;
    attack2 = 8;
}
if (attack == "j9"){
    attack1 = 9;
    attack2 = 9;
}
```

^^

That whole thing may be replaced by:

```
attack1 = alphabet.find(attack[0])
attack2 = (int) attack[1]
```